# node js upload size unit is strange

Tags: node.js, file, size, filesize, units-of-measurement

I am working on upload module of my server and I set file uploads with multiparty. I am currently trying to limit the upload size simply i a doing something like this

```
req.on("data", function(dt) {
                bytes += dt.length;
                if (bytes > 2048) {
                req.connection.destroy();
                console.log("connection destroyed due to huge file size");
                }
                console.log(bytes);

            });
```

I thought this length is in bytes and tried to limit it with 2mb
but i noticed this unit is a bit strange for testing i uploaded a 148 kb file but the length of the variable i created so far is 421 it is neither in bits nor bytes why it is so strange number? where do this extra ~300k come from?[image: on top 421 is length of variable bytes and at bottom the size comes frommultiparty whic is accurate]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `filesystem module` for checking size of the file?

E.g.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var stats = fs.statSync("myfile.txt");
var fileSizeInBytes = stats.size;
```

Comment: the point to learn this on air while the data is still coming